# proper C function formatting with indent

Tags: c, indentation

I can't quite wrangle indent to do what I want. The first thing is that it changes functions to look like:

```
double  
func1() {
```

When I would want them to look like:

```
 double func1() {
```

That is the main item to get resolved. The other thing it's doing is making things look like:

```
  long int hi = 100;

  long int lo = 1;

  long int mid = 50;
```

And I would prefer it to be:

```
  long int hi = 100;
  long int lo = 1;
  long int mid = 50;
```

My current .indent.pro looks like this:

```
 -bad -bap -br -brf -brs -cdw -ce -cli3 -fc1 -nbc -ncs -npcs -ss   -sob -nut -v -nbc
```

Any ideas on what I can change to make functions and variable assignments look the way I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add -npsl 
replace -bad with -nbad
```